# How to ask about someone's study?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

Suppose I meet a stranger at park. And I want to ask about his study,i.e., what course he is studying. Then which one the following is true:

1. What do you study?
2. What are you studying?

I think first one is correct and till now I was using that. But I just watched an English tutorial video on YouTube ([here](https://youtu.be/IhQt_fxGOcw?t=97)) in which they use (2). So I get confused. I am not asking about what currently he is studying.

Thanks

Comment: Please include a link to the video.

Comment: Related: [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91015/what-is-the-difference-between-you-are-being-and-you-are/91017#91017)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Both are absolutely correct

and in most cases, they are interchangeable.  Unfortunately, like many other things in a language, it depends on the context.

If I am a college student living in a dormitory, and I ask my room mate

> What are you studying?

They might tell me which subject they are studying at that moment.

> I'm studying Math right now, but I'll be studying Spanish in an hour.

If I ask my room mate

> What do you study?

He/she might respond with a broader answer, since I didn't use the gerund (present participle) verb tense.  To say `studying` suggests that the study is happening right now.

> I study microbiology

---

In another context, let's say that you are attending a family reunion.  You're going to be around a lot of relatives, and generally, people that know you.  At such an event, it is inevitable that a question comes about your education, assuming you are in college/school.

Consider your uncle asking you

> It is great that you're in college.  What are you studying?

In this sense, the uncle is not interested in getting a course name for an answer, he's interested in the broader answer: *microbiology (from above)*

Also, in this sense, both questions mean the same thing.  So if your uncle says, instead

> It is great that you're in college.  What do you study?

You would answer with the same answer.

Comment: Actually I am not asking for that moment. Both person are only talking at the moment, none of them is studying. Though they used -ing.

Answer (score 3):

Both would be understood, but there's a slightly different flavour. I think the "-ing" form is better when talking about some ongoing education:

> I'm a student at X University.
>
> Oh, what are you studying?

contrast with

> I have been taking some extra lessons.
>
> Oh, what do you study?
>
> Conversational English relating to medicine.

here we are talking about specific items of study, probably for a limited period of time.

Answer (score 3):

The two phrases can mean the same thing.

Since the two persons are introducing themselves, 2 is inquiring about the person's [major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_(academic)) (AmE), or, as Wikipedia puts it:

> the academic discipline to which an undergraduate student formally commits.

This is in contrast to, say, two friends who are inquiring about the current/up coming term. In such a case, 2 inquires about the particular subjects one might be studying that term, such as biology, math, and economics. This is because, presumably, the friends already know each other's committed disciplines.

Question 1 usually inquires about one's committed disciple. So, Kabir could **also** have asked 1 in this case, and it would have meant the same thing as 2. Hence, Jackie responds "B.E.". We can infer that B.E. is Jackie's committed discipline, in either case.