# Choosing between simple present & present continuous

Tags: present-continuous

If I intend to ask about somebody's major of study, should I use
**Simple presents: what do you study?**
or
**present continuous: what are you studying?**

I understand that the simple present tense is used for habitual actions, and the present continuous tense is used for actions happening around now.

While studying is a temporal action occurring around the present, it takes a considerable amount of time to be considered happening in the present moment, making it more likely to be habitual.

Please indicate the correct form and share why you chose it.

Comment: *Study* is a general question, while *studying* is about this term or this minute in the library.

Comment: The idiomatic way is "What is your major?"

Comment: "What do you study?" would be asked of someone who spends a lot of time dipping into various fields of study; one would ask a student "What are you studying?"

Comment: For that purpose, *What are you studying?* would be idiomatic.

Comment: @Barmar - "What is your major?" would not be idiomatic in British English, as we don't use that expression for a student's main subject.

Comment: The actual question asks about somebody's major, so it's reasonable to assume "What is your major?" would fit.

Comment: An entomologist might answer "What do you study?" with "insects", but "What are you studying?" with "The ant colonies of Borneo". An entomology student might answer both questions with "entomology".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple present, or present continuous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290364/simple-present-or-present-continuous)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ask about someone's study?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97401/how-to-ask-about-someones-study)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Present Continuous vs Simple Present](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150480/present-continuous-vs-simple-present)